# Want to copy column and insert n times below

Tags: events, stata

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
Date | a (1) | a (2) | a (3) | b (1) | b (2) | b (3) | c (1) ...
```

what I would love to have though is:

```
Date | ID | 1 | 2 | 3
ID: a, b, c
```

Therefore, I would have to copy and paste the dates n (here: 3, i.e. a,b,c) times below each other to cover it for all IDs. Is there any way to do this quicker than renaming and copy pasting it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not very clear. If you have a Stata dataset you should be able to show real variable names and a token data example.

This may help:

```
clear 
input Date a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3 
2016 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
end 

rename a* ya* 
rename b* yb* 
rename c* yc* 
reshape long ya yb yc, i(Date) j(which) 
reshape long y, i(Date which) j(Id) string
reshape wide y, i(Date Id) j(which)

l

     +--------------------------+
     | Date   Id   y1   y2   y3 |
     |--------------------------|
  1. | 2016    a    1    2    3 |
  2. | 2016    b    4    5    6 |
  3. | 2016    c    7    8    9 |
     +--------------------------+
```

EDIT:

This is easier:

```
clear 
input Date a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3 
2016 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
end 

rename *1 y1* 
rename *2 y2* 
rename *3 y3* 
reshape long y1 y2 y3, i(Date) j(Id) string 

list 

     +--------------------------+
     | Date   Id   y1   y2   y3 |
     |--------------------------|
  1. | 2016    a    1    2    3 |
  2. | 2016    b    4    5    6 |
  3. | 2016    c    7    8    9 |
     +--------------------------+
```

If this doesn't answer the question, you may need to come back with a more specific example. (Don't abstract; show realistic details.)

Comment: Thank you for your edits and immediate response! I will check if this solves the problem and will get back to you :)